# Python: How can I raise an error if two keys in a dictionary have the same value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I wrote a function that swaps the keys and values in a dictionary.

```
def reverse_dict(my_dict):
    my_dict2 = dict((v,k) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems())
    return my_dict2
```

For this purpose, I cannot have different keys with the same value.
Example:

```
random_dict = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1}
```

How can I throw a `ValueError` if a value occurs more than once in the input dictionary?

Comment: Just check if the current value already exists as a key in the result dict as you go through it. But you should post your function - it might need another way of doing it.

Comment: You can find the duplicate values with `[k for k, v in Counter(my_dict.values()).items() if v> 1]` if you need to know which they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the `len(my_dict2) == len(my_dict)`. . . If they aren't the same length, raise your `ValueError`

```
def reverse_dict(my_dict):
    my_dict2 = dict((v,k) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems())
    if len(my_dict2) != len(my_dict):
        raise ValueError('Disallowed duplicate value in dictionary')
    return my_dict2
```

---

As indicated in the comments, you could use a dict comprehension instead of `dict` and a generator expression:

```
my_dict2 = {v: k for k,v in my_dict.iteritems()}
```

It'll be slightly more terse (and performant) if you really are targeting python2.7+

Comment: Why not a dict comprehension?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy -- Because OP didn't use one.  Maybe OP wants to maintain backwards compatibility with python2.6 for one reason or another . . .

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the comprehension, and check as you go:

```
#!python2
def reverse_dict(my_dict):
    my_dict2 = {}
    for k,v in my_dict.iteritems():
        if v not in my_dict2:
            my_dict2[v] = k
        else:
            raise ValueError(v)
    return my_dict2

random_dict = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1}
random_dict2 = reverse_dict(random_dict)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    random_dict2 = reverse_dict(random_dict)
  File "C:\test.py", line 8, in reverse_dict
    raise ValueError(v)
ValueError: 1
```

This way you can get an indication of what value was the duplicate as well.

Comment: Correction -- You'll get an indication of one value that was duplicate.  If there are multiple dupes, you'll only see one.  That aside, I like the answer.  It's the only one which has a chance of short-circuiting early (though real measurements would have to be done on actual data to see if that's any benefit for OP's average case).  +1 from me.

Comment: @mgilson, thanks, thus the comment `an indication`.  Like most exceptions, you fix the one that raised the exception and then the next error (duplicate) will raise :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if the length of `random_dict.values()` isn't equals `set(random_dict.values())`.

Let's see:

```
>>> random_dict = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1}
>>> len(random_dict.values())
3
>>> len(set(random_dict.values()))
2
>>> random_dict.values()
dict_values([1, 2, 1])
>>> set(random_dict.values())
{1, 2}
```

So it's simple:

```
>>> if not len(random_dict.values()) == len(set(random_dict.values())):
...     raise ValueError
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
values = my_dict.values()
if len(values) != len(set(values)):
    raise ValueError
```

before you transpose key and value

```
def reverse_dict(my_dict):
    values = my_dict.values()
    if len(values) != len(set(values)):
        raise ValueError
    my_dict2 = dict((v,k) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems())
    return my_dict2
```

Comment: It seems a waste to construct a throw-away set when you're already going to construct another dict in the next step (on which you could perform the same check)

Comment: @mgilson you are suggesting the check after creating a new dict, while I am saying do the check before creating a new dict. both have merit.

Comment: Why?  What's the benefit to checking _before_?  You'll use more memory and take about twice as long in the common case (no Exception).  In the uncommon case, you save about half the memory of the dict on python3.x, but not so much on python2.x since `dict.values()` also creates a new list...

Comment: ok. If the common case is no Exception, then I agree with your observation. OP didn't mention anything about the length of the dict or the distribution of values.